# jQuery Code doesn't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

```
$screenWidth = $(document).width();
  if ($screenWidth < 980) {
    $('#show-menu').removeAttr('checked')
  }
```

This code doesn't work in IE9. Maybe jQuery isn't even loaded?
https://alphafotograf.de/
If the checkbox is checked, the menu on the left will be visible. If the screen width is below 980px, the checkbox isn't checked and the menu isn't visible.
Please ignore the console errors, they are not related to this.

Comment: You need to provide more content in the question, but the answer *was* buried in the page anyway, so +1 to ease the pain of the down-votes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
$('#show-menu').prop('checked',false)
```

instead of

```
$('#show-menu').removeAttr('checked')
```

You should always use `prop` for `checked` properties (consistent across browsers).

When I run the site in Chrome's F12 tools, I see two errors that stop execution before it gets to this line of code:

**Line 107:** "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL*"

```
$('iframe').load( function() { $('iframe').contents().find("head") .append($("
```

**Line 57:** "*Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*"

```
jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"html": true,"container": "body"});
```

Comment: I notice that code is not in a DOM ready handler. What do you get if you `alert($screenWidth)` at that point in the code?

Comment: I also notice I am getting error on the page before it even hits that line :)

Comment: Check your console... and the revisions above. I am unable to breakpoint the required line as there *is* a preceding error.

Comment: when i remove the script, it still doesnt work in ie9. so ie doesnt seem to understand checked="checked" as an attribute of a checkbox.

Comment: ok, i removed the iframe script. its working now, thanks a lot :)